# Go to openfile Intellij ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, ideavim

Normally, I can select opened file in Intellij using this shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. But I want to remapping shortcut with Ideavim. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mapping to `<Action>(SelectInProjectView)`. E.g.: `map <leader>s <Action>(SelectInProjectView)`

Comment: it works but Intellij show confirm dialog: `:action SelectInProjectView`, then I need an extra keystroke to complete this action.

Comment: I need extra help from you. Thanks.

Comment: This is surprising, there should be no additional dialogs. Could you please show a screenshot? Here or using https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM?u=1

Comment: [Screenshort](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/logbasex.github.io/ideavim.png)

Comment: `nnoremap ,o :action SelectInProjectView` I use this binding to map action above.

Comment: Oh, I see. You should put `<CR>` at the end of mapping (enter key). You can alternatively use new mapping syntax as in my example (required the latest version of the plugin 0.61)

Comment: It works like a charm.Thank you so much :D